# Dropout voltage of a LDO (MIC37100)

Tags: voltage, ldo

I'm trying to figure out the dropout voltage for a 1.5V Output MIC37100

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic37100.pdf

From the datasheet above, it shows the dropout voltage for when Iout = 500mA to be 350mV Max.

This doesn't make sense to me because the Vin range is 2.25 Min. Which means that you're already going to have a 750mV dropout voltage. Am I reading this right? Is that how the drop out works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that this device has multiple restrictions, not just "low dropout".

1. You can't use Vin less than 2.25V;
2. You can have an output set to 1.24V, but **Vin still should be above 2.25V**. So yes, the dropout in this case will be more than 750 mV;
3. But if you use Vin = 2.25V, **you CAN have Vout at high as 1.9V** with Iout up to 500mA.
4. If you need Iout as 1A, you can safely use this regulator with Vout=1.75V (drop of 500mV maximum) with Vin = 2.25V.
5. If you need 3.3V at 500 mA, the "low dropout" (350mV) means that you can tolerate drops in Vin down to 3.7V.
6. But under no circumstances the Vin can be below 2.25V.

Does it make sense now?

Comment: It does, thank you. I was hung up on the change in Vout spec, meaning that the output voltage had to be within -1% of 1.5V regardless of input voltage (>2.25) or load current.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MIC37100-1.5BS-TR/MIC37100-1.5BS-TR-ND/1029257

For example, if you look at this datasheet it says max dropout voltage is .5V. But if Vin = 2.25V Min and the Output is fixed 1.5V then the dropout voltage is a non factor?

Comment: @hybridchem, I feel some disconnect here. The working dropout is the difference Vin-Vout. It varies with whatever Vin is coming in. The "max dropout"  doesn't mean the maximum Vin-Vout for a regulator, it actually means the **minimum Vin-Vout** the regulator can handle while maintaining voltage regulation. If you already have a large Vin-Vout, the "max dropout" is not any limiting "factor". It becomes a limiting factor only when your Vout is set to be too close to Vin.

Answer (score 2):

From the datasheet:

> For output voltages below 2.25V, dropout voltage is
>   the input-to-output voltage differential with the minimum input voltage being 2.25V.

This is provided as a footnote for the Dropout Voltage specification.

Comment: Indeed, I read this. Isn't the differential the the same as Vin-Vout?

Comment: @hybridchem your datasheet also covers 2.5, 3.3, and adjustable output parts, where 2.25 V would not be more than 350 mV above the output voltage. So the 350 mV dropout applies to those part numbers, and the 2.25 V minimum applies to the variants with output voltage less than 1.9 V.

Comment: So you're saying that table of Drop out voltage means nothing to versions < 2.25V..

Comment: @hybridchem, the table of Dropout voltages has a Note#6 attached that explains the restrictions.